How to display kitty window id in window at all times?
I'm using a program (vim-slime) that needs me to tell it which kitty window to send text to.
I can get the kitty window id with:
env | grep KITTY_WINDOWS_ID

But that involves exiting any console or whatever I'm already doing in that window whose ID I wish to obtain.
Is there a way to make the kitty window ID display somewhere (e.g. in a corner) at all times, so it can be obtained at a glance?

You can probably put that into something like p10k
